# Grey Out/Disable menu item in eclipse plugin programatically

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, menuitem, jface, popupmenu

I have created an pop up menu and preferences page in eclipse. I would like to enable/disable the menu item based on the values stored by user in preferences page.

How can I achieve it ?

Following is the code.

Plugin.xml - Added a menu option and a command associated with it.

```xml
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command
        defaultHandler="com.eclipse.plugin.commands.ActionHandler"
        id="com.eclipse.plugin.commands.Action"
        name="Action">
    </command>
</extension>

<extension 
    point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
        <menu
            id="Menu"
            label="CustomMenu">
            <command
                commandId="com.eclipse.plugin.commands.Action"
                label="Action"
                style="push"
                tooltip="">
            </command>
        </menu>
    </menuContribution>
 </extension>
```

The below handler is used to perform action on clicking on menu item.

```java
public class ActionHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        //some action here
        return null;
    }
}
```

I need to disable the menu items when the user clicks of 'Ok' button on preferences page

```java
public class CustomPreferences extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {
        .....
        @Override
        public boolean performOk() {
        // Here i need to disable or gey out menu option
            super.performOk();
            return true;
        }
        .....
    }
```

I have read that Handler can be defined with conditions (activeWhen) under which  we can define the conditions under which the handlers are valid for a command.
How can we achieve it here ?

Comment: Show us your code for the pop-up

Comment: You would probably have to use the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point to define a property tester that you can use in a `systemTest` in the `visibleWhen` element of the `menuContribution`